# Can I pull a subset of a CSS grid (say a full column/row) using JQuery from one page to another?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Basically I have a CSS grid that is populated. Let's say 5 x 5. Is there any way I can transpose area 1 x 5 (first column) from one page onto another? Or even just move it around on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has a clone function https://api.jquery.com/clone/

And from one page to another, you could use [browser storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to copy this dom element, and past it to you second page

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you add a bit of colour, which selector would I use if I wanted to clone only the first column?

Comment: Can you provide some code, and some tests you've done with this function ?